# Proof that only a certain amount of points can fit in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle, rectangles

> Prove that no more than 8 points can fit in a rectangle with sides d
>   and 2d if any 2 points have to be at least d units away from each
>   other.

I have proved that no more than 6 points can fit in such a rectangle using the fact that between 3 points (not on a straight line) there is a triangle with area at least `sqrt(3)/4 d^2` (this is the area of an equilateral triangle with side d).
Does anybody know if that's correct and if there is a more formal way of proving that?
Many thanks

Comment: Hint: the end points of any diagonal of a circle of radius $d/2$ units are necessarily $d$ units apart. Try and see if or how or how many such circles would fit in the rectangle in question.

Comment: yes, that is what I thought, to consider as if every point has a circle around him of radius 'd/2'. this gives me the answer of 6 points max, but isn't considered a formal proof

Comment: Don't forget that those circles can reach outside the given rectangle. So if the combined area of the six circles is larger than that of the rectangle this does not rule out the possibility that the centers of those circles could still all be inside the rectangle. This is still a good idea. Calculating the area of non-overlapping circles (or in higher dimensions volume of balls) is a very useful attack to problems like this. You just need to take the "border effects" into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using triangles does not work quite that simply, because an isosceles triangle with two sides of length $d$, the angle between them $\theta$, has the third side $\ge d$, if $\theta\in[\pi/3,\pi)$ (or between $60$ and $180$ degrees). But if $\theta$ is close to $180$ degrees its area $A=\frac12d^2\sin\theta$ will be close to zero.

Instead you can divide the rectangle into 8 squares with side length $d/2$. If there were more than 8 points by the pigeonhole principle at least two of them will fall into the same square and consequently have distance $\le d/\sqrt2<d$ violating the given rules.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: @Simone: thanks for spotting and fixing the typo :-)